# Ошибка: Нарушение прав доступа. Подключение dll

Tags: c++, dll

В библиотеке есть функции на экспорт. Одна из них `getMethod()`. Она возвращает указатель на объект класса (`CGradDescSol` являющегося наследником `ISolver`), который не имеет полей. При попытке обратится к методу данного класса через "разыменовывание" происходит ошибка. При попытке создать указатель на интерфейс (`ISolver`), а потом присвоить `getMethod()` возвращает нарушение прав доступа. 
Библиотека загружается, функция тоже.

Объявление F:

```
typedef ISolver* (_cdecl *PROCFUN)(void);

ISolver *solve;
solve = (*F)(); // ERR
solve->getSolution(newpara,&f1);
```

Функция в dll имеет вид:

```
 extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) ISolver* getMethod() {return  new CGradDescSol;}
```

ISolver - интерфейс:

```
class ISolver {
public:
    __declspec(dllexport) virtual void solve(MyFunction *f, Array<double> &x0) = 0;
    __declspec(dllexport) virtual void getSolution(Array<double> &x, MyFunction *f) = 0;
};
```

CGradDescSol - наследник, состоит только из реализации виртуальных методов.

Comment: `solve = (*F)();` — переменная-указатель `F` как инициализируется?